# Magento "My Account" link section

Tags: magento, authentication, module

I'm currently developing a helpticket module for magento.
After you login an go to My Account you see a menu on the left side.

I already managed to get a link to my module in that menu.
I now want to show this menu when you open my module.

Does anybody has some information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In you frontend layout xml file for the module you will need code simmilar to this:

```
<HANDLE_FOR_YOUR_MODULE translate="label">
    <label>LABEL FOR CUSTOM MODULE</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
</HANDLE_FOR_YOUR_MODULE>
```

The update tag is the important part

Answer (score 0):

go to magento admin, Under system->configuration->developer ... turn on template and block hints.

Then when you go back to the frontend you will be able to see which template is used for the 'My Account Menu'. You can just include this template to your modules layout and your module should show the menu.